# Executing Java-compiled JavaScript file using Mozilla/Apache Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm coming up to a bit of a problem, but not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've grabbed the latest copy of Rhino, but the API docs are 404ing, and the latest version available on Internet Archive aren't complete!

I have a JavaScript file with a number of functions. I've compiled this into a .class file and can access this in Java to do print() and such.

What I can't work out is how to access the JavaScript functions' return values, or to have the script run and return a value.

```
    CompiledClass instance = new CompiledClass();
    instance.main(arg);
```

... works fine, but main doesn't (and can't) return a value. If I have a method in JavaScript called say countApples(), which returns an int, how do I access this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Java it will probably be easiest to use the new [`javax.scripting`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) API introduced with JSR-223.

A modified form of the Rhino engine is now included in the Java standard library since JDK 6.

That's how I've always used JavaScript from Java, and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `javap` to find out the name of the method and call it directly (don't go via `main()`).